# Automatic root login in Debian 6.0 without GUI (xserver)

Tags: linux, debian

Is there any simple and straightforward way in which I can set my Debian 6.0 box to **automatically login**, at startup, with the root account on the console?

There is no GUI (xserver) installed on the machine.

Comment: If I may pry: why?

Comment: @Daniel: it's a homework project demo virtual machine, I have to send it to my professor, and he is like "please don't bother me with login credentials"

Comment: You may also find funny that root password is "password"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have a Debian install handy, but this method works for Slackware and should apply just as well to any system which uses inittab.

As root, edit the file `/etc/inittab`.  Find a line that looks something like the following:

```
c1:1235:respawn:/sbin/agetty 38400 tty1 linux
```

Replace that line with (or better yet, comment it out and add) one which reads as follows:

```
c1:1235:respawn:/sbin/login -f root tty1 </dev/tty1 >/dev/tty1 2>&1
```

Save the file and reboot.

Comment: I made a little correction: 1:1235:respawn:/bin/login -f root tty1 </dev/tty1 >/dev/tty1 2>&1 it works. thank you

Comment: Nice, this works for me. In the interest of learning, what does this line actually mean? @goldPseudo

Comment: @lppier This inittab line just tells the first console ("c1:"), when initialized under runlevels 1, 2, 3 or 5 (":1235:") to run the command "/sbin/login -f root...2>&1" (force login without password) instead of "/sbin/agetty...linux", and to restart the process whenever it's terminated (":respawn:").  The whole "</dev/tty1 >/dev/tty1 2>&1" bit is to force the session input and output to go through the console (which IIRC was necessary for reasons), but I honestly have no idea why that first "tty1" is in there :/ You should be able to `man inittab` and `man login` for further details.

Comment: I don't think the first tty1 does anything. I removed it and nothing changed.

Comment: @gd1 are just works `1:1235:respawn:/bin/login -f usrname tty1 </dev/tty1 >/dev/tty1 2>&1
`

Answer (score 4):

You can enable the autologin by modifying the inittab file.

Using any editor Open the file inittab. I have used vim editor

```
#vim /etc/inittab
```

Serach for the line.

```
1:2345:respawn:/sbin/getty 38400 tty1
```

Replace with as follow

```
1:2345:respawn:/sbin/mingetty --autologin <user-name>  --noclear tty1
```

After modifying the inittab restart the system.

Note: before modifying the inittab, keep the backup of it.

Comment: Actually, I accepted the other answer just because it is more similar to the solution I actually applied. Nevertheless, I'm sure your solution is good as well as the other. +1

Comment: `mingetty` dos not exist on fresh installed Debian 6 and I guess it's need real console (KB) and monitor, do not work on virtual console .

Answer (score 2):

Both answers from here didn't work on my os,

I use [CUBIAN](https://github.com/cubieplayer/Cubian) which is an Debian wheezy based os for ARMv7 on Cubieboard

and my solution (working for me) is using rungetty :

install **rungetty**

edit **/etc/inittab**

comment out

```
1:2345:respawn:/sbin/getty 38400 tty1
```

and add

```
1:2345:respawn:/sbin/rungetty tty1 --autologin YOUR_USER_NAME
```

edit **.bash_profile** and at the bottom add

```
if [ -z "$DISPLAY" ] && [ $(tty) = /dev/tty1 ]; then
while true
do
startx --
sleep 10
done
fi
```

then it worked !

Thanks to **MeanDean** on [Debian user forum](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?t=29333).