# Autologin as root or as any other user in Linux in console mode

Tags: linux, kernel, root

my system requires to run automatically at start up. so, i did write a simple module and registered it inside /inittab. it automatically runs at start up but the problem is when i turn on the computer it should automatically log on as a root.

is there any way to do this?

by the way im using 2.6.29 of the kernel version.

thanks in advance.

Comment: ... Why would you write a module to log in as root? Wouldn't it be easier to just modify the startup scripts?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: It doesn't sound like "module" is being used in the sense of "kernel module", since `inittab` is somehow involved.

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/407914/automatic-root-login-in-debian-6-0-without-gui-xserver

Comment: @Daniel Andersson, i already tried this options and came with error:
`/bin/sh: exec: line 1: /sbin/login: not found` so where is login file?

Comment: You haven't told us which operating system (=distribution in this case) you are using, but an easy way to find the `login` binary is to run `which login`, which will most likely say `/bin/login` for you.

Comment: im using linux kernel, version: 2.6.29, downloaded from http://www.kernel.org/. and also i found login file in /bin but nothing happened when i changed sbin/login to bin/login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the way using the existing `init` fails, use the kernel's settings.

When you boot, add `init=/bin/bash` to your kernel command-line - this forces it to bypass Upstart and should give you a single user shell, since the kernel spawns `bash` off as the root user.

Comment: thanks new123456 :) your name and answer are cool! that is what im looking for. And if you know please tell me how to run a program after getting bash. Let's say in root folder, there is a "main" program that prints "Hello World" 100 times. when kernel starts and get's bash console main program should run. please any ideas! thanks.

Comment: @mashur Automatically? Login and edit the program into`~/.bashrc`. So, for root, add `/hello` to the end of `/root/.bashrc`.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the runlevel to 1 and it is rhel/centos or similar distributions, and there is no other security systems set up, it will automatically log in as root. You then would have to start various services such as networking and programs yourself.

Comment: hello jhonshen64!
thanks to your express answer :) and i did as u said but right here im lil bit confusing.

after changing runlevel to 1:

`Enabling swap space:                                       [  OK  ]
INIT: Entering runlevel: 1
Entering non-interactive startup

Telling INIT to go to single user mode.
init: /dev/initctl: No such file or directory
INIT: no more processes left in this runlevel`

So, do these these messages telling me to write a char device driver named /dev/initctl and run my program through that driver?

Comment: in order to do autorun i used init=/bin/bash and to run an application after getting logging on, wrote a runnable script (sysV script)
PROBLEM SOLVED