# Automatic root login in Debian 8.0 (console only)

Tags: linux, debian

Is there any simple and straightforward way in which I can set my Debian 8.2 box to automatically login, at startup, with the root account on the console?

There is no GUI installed on the machine.

Following instructions from [Automatic root login in Debian 6.0 without GUI (xserver)](https://superuser.com/questions/407914/automatic-root-login-in-debian-6-0-without-gui-xserver) does not work (files don't exist, options are deprecated).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The file `/etc/inittab` is not used under `systemd` any longer. If you wanted, you could install `systemv` and you would find yourself a brand new `inittab`, but this would mean walking backward like crabs.

You can instead edit the file `/lib/systemd/system/getty@.service` and change the line

```
  ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty --noclear %I $TERM
```

to

```
  ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty --noclear -a root %I $TERM
```

This just follows from the agetty manual page, which states, among other things:

> `-a`, `--autologin username`
>
> Log the specified user automatically in without asking for a login name  and  password. The `-f username` option is added to the `/bin/login` command line by default. The `--login-options` option changes this default behavior and then only `\u` is replaced by the `username` and no other option is added to the login command
>                 line.

To be sure, I just tested this on my Debian VM, and it works fine.

Comment: Was looking for inintab replacement on systemd, good answer!

Comment: Still works in Debian 9. Tested in combination with nfsroot on some diskless boxes. And I recommend to keep in mind Arnie97's advice (I am commenting here, as this is the route I've taken, I'm just that lazy for the moment :-)

Answer (score 13):

DO NOT edit the units in `/lib/systemd` directly,
since those are managed by installed packages,
and would be overwritten during package upgrades.

Instead, use `$ sudo systemctl edit getty@.service` to [create a drop-in unit](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/systemd#Drop-in_files) at `/etc/systemd/system/getty@.service.d/override.conf` with the following contents:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty --noclear --autologin your_user_name %I $TERM
```

It has the same effects as @MariusMatutiae's answer, but won't be touched during system upgrades.

The first line selects the `[Service]` section to override.
The second line explicitly clears the `ExecStart` entry -- otherwise the original `ExecStart` in `/lib/systemd` would still be effective, since [multiple `ExecStart` directives are allowed in a single `oneshot` service unit](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#ExecStart=).
And the last line defines the new `ExecStart` command line, which is already explained in @MariusMatutiae's answer.

Refer to the [systemd.unit(5) manual pages](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html#Description) for more details and examples.

Answer (score -1):

You can edit the file /lib/systemd/system/getty@.service and change the line

ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty --noclear %I $TERM

to

ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty --skip-login --login-options "-f root" %I 38400 linux

for auto login as root user

Comment: I see you're new here, this question has already been answered and you just copied the answer..